# undefined reference to `std::thread::_State::~_State()' while creating RSA_PrivateKey

Tags: c++, qt, botan

Compiler complaining undefined reference to std::thread::_State::~_State() when I am trying to create RSA_PrivateKey object in Botan C++.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <botan/rsa.h>
#include <botan/auto_rng.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
std::unique_ptr<Botan::RandomNumberGenerator> rng(new Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG);
cout << rng->name();

// this line caused the error
 std::unique_ptr<Botan::RSA_PrivateKey> theKey(new Botan::RSA_PrivateKey(*rng.get(),1024));

return a.exec();
}
```

Error shows like this:
[Error when creating RSA_PrivateKey in Botan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPGC6.png)

I'm really not sure why the compiler is complaining. I need help, thanks in advance.

I added the botan library as a static library using the ".a" file. I did it by right-clicking the project folder > add library > External Library. I tried to compile in debug.

[Added botan like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbw0K.png)

OS: Windows 7

Compiler：Qt 5.11.2 MinGW 32-bit

Comment: Was everything compiled with the same compiler and the same settings? Can you produce this error without QT, just standard library+Botan.

Comment: You mean doing the same thing in other IDE like Code::Blocks?

Comment: Yes, same compiler and settings

Comment: I don't think this anything to do with Botan.  I think it's to do with std::thread (which I think is being brought in by Qt).  What happens if `main` is just `{return QCoreApplication(argc,argv).exec(); }`?

Comment: No, I don't think Fire Lancer means "doing the same thing in other IDE".  He means "how was the static library generated"?  Was that same compiler and settings?

Comment: the main can run when it is just {return QCoreApplication(argc,argv).exec(); }, I built the static library using mingw32-make (MinGW 8.1.0) which is not from Qt. Should I built it again using Qt MinGW 5.11.2 32-bit compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of `Botan::RSA_PrivateKey` :

```
Botan::RSA_PrivateKey rsa(*rng.get(),1024);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have change code but the compiler still complaining the same undefined reference

Comment: @CloudWave How did you use of `botan` library? where did you use of static libraries? what is your operating system? windows or linux? are you trying to compile in `release` or `debug`??? explain exactly.....

Comment: @CloudWave why did you add `.a` file??? archive files are for linux os as static library files. you should add `.lib` file to your project instead of `.a`.

Comment: He is using MinGW, which is ported GCC+other stuff.

Comment: @FireLancer  mingw's static library format is `*.a` either for windows and linux??? is this true?

Comment: Yes, I believe it uses the GCC .a format regardless, but has some special extra support added to deal with the `.lib` import libraries for DLL's only (along with anything else needed for DLL compared to so).